# How to reduce execution time on query with right join?

Tags: h2

My query with right join works fine if I don't have too much data. But when I have 500 rows in my table or more, the query can take 5 minutes or even more.

How can I reduce or improve the execution time of this query:

```
SELECT dlocation.USER_NAME,dtransaction.USER_NAME
FROM dlocation RIGHT JOIN dtransaction 
ON (dtransaction.locationid= dlocation.id) and (dtransaction.isinternational = 
dlocation.isinternational) and (dtransaction.USER_NAME= dlocation.USER_NAME)
WHERE dtransaction.typeId = 'Charge' and (dtransaction.USER_NAME is null or 
dlocation.USER_NAME is null)
```

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server? Those are two very different database products

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am running the queries on H2 database which is based on Oracle...

Comment: H2 is most certainly not "based on" Oracle, it is a completely different database product

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry about that, I was sure it is more like Oracle. Anyhow, I'm running the queries on H2 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of your query can be improved by adding the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on dtransaction (typeId, USER_NAME);

create index ix2 on dlocation (id, isinternational, USER_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to request H2 to show the execution plan for such query.

For this you need the EXPLAIN command [http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#explain]. You just need to add it in front of the query under performance investigation.

As this is a join, you need to make sure you've no tablescan left in your execution plan. In your case, you likely need to add indexes.